# Suddenly, dozens of Late Answers (old ones) in the review queue

Tags: discussion

Something seems to have happened to the Review queue. I see over 30 posts in the [Late Answers queue](https://patents.stackexchange.com/review/late-answers), and after going through a handful of them, I started noticing that the answer dates are old (over a year old). Is anyone else seeing this? Any explanation?

I'm holding off on completing any more of these reviews for now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This is that something.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/267080/1438) The very short answer is that I expanded the pool of people eligable for having their late answers added to that queue. It... was very effective in terms of adding more review tasks because it wasn't time limited. All eligible answers going back to the start of the site got added yesterday. But the sudden spike will dissipate as people complete the reviews. (So don't stop! ;-)

Once things settle down, I expect the effect of the change will be to add an extra answer or two to the queue every now and then. It should not be a continual flood of tasks.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! I didn't want to "destroy the evidence" in case it was a glitch in the system. I'll work through them if someone else doesn't get to them first.